# Masking a whole image in texture mode

Tags: texture-painting, masking

I'd like to know how I can mask (if possible) my whole image in texture paint mode, so at the end, I don't get unnecessary paint and colors in my diffuse texture.
I wanted to put the following image as a mask to my diffuse texture, but seems like I can't find the right place to do it

[image]

Comment: I don't think mask is what you are after. Using that image any texture painting you do to the axe will be applied to the white area. You can setup another image to use in texture paint so that that image doesn't get any paint.

Answer (score 1):

Black and white images can be used as a Mask in the texture paint mode, setting them up in the Slots panel. 
The cool thing is that you can use that image you have there as a mask, and invert it to paint outside that area as well.
[video on mask use with mask tool and stencil mask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EADlsrK1LQ)
[image: slots panel mask use]